# Getting Element not interactable exception

Tags: python, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

```
Documentation      Login Test in fragment mode with appleid
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem


*** Variables ***
${email}    https://account.booking.com/sign-in?
${chrome}    chrome

*** Test Cases ***
login_test_with_appleid_chrome
   Open booking.com on chrome browser
      open browser    ${email}     ${chrome}
      maximize browser window
      sleep    10

   Click on sign in with appleid
     click element     xpath://a[@title='Sign in with Apple']
     sleep   5
     ${handle} =    Switch Window   NEW # Select latest opened window
     sleep    5

Enter username and click on Continue with email
     input text    xpath://input[@id='account_name_text_field']     abc

#     click element    xpath://div[@id='sign_in_form']
#     sleep    1
#     click element    xpath://button[@id='sign-in']
#     sleep    1
     click element     xpath://i[@class='shared-icon icon_sign_in']
     sleep    3
```

When I am clicking on sing-in arrow it is giving me Element not interactable exception. I have tried press Keys as well but still getting same issue

Can any one help me with actual xpath of the element

**Error Code**

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element
<i class="shared-icon icon_sign_in" data-isla81n27wdid="289"></i> is not clickable at point (431, 284)
. Other element would receive the click: <input type="text" id="account_name_text_field" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-requ
   ired="true" required="required" spellcheck="false" class="force-ltr form-textbox form-textbox-text  form-textbox-entered " aria-invalid="false" autofocus="" data-isla81n27wdid="240
   " data-focus-method="key">
```

Comment: As per the DOM, the `<button>` which contains the `<i class="shared-icon icon_sign_in">` has `id` attribute. You can use the `ID`  or CSS selector `#sign-in` of that button tag to click on that arrow button.

Comment: I have tried below xapth but no xpath is working                          1)//button[@id='sign-in']                                                              
 2)//div[@class='signin fade-in']/div/button/i                                
 3)//i[@class='shared-icon icon_sign_in']                                      
 4)//button[@id='sign-in']/i                                                                                   
 5)press keys      None      ENTER     but for all getting element not interactable

Comment: Have tried the same in Python - [Python Code](https://pastebin.com/sdBJUTux). It has worked for me. it does click on the arrow button and move to password field.

Comment: Also tried with Xpath - `//button[@id='sign-in']`, and its working.